# how can i store data created in angular to a file in node js

Tags: node.js, angular, bpmn

i already search about how to save  data in a file in node.js

```
save(): void {
    this.modeler.saveXML((err: any, xml: any) => console.log('Result of saving XML: ', err, xml));
  }
}
```

Comment: But what you want to achieve? Do you want to save that file on your server file system?  Or do you want to download it on the client side. You must ask more precise questions.

Comment: yes i wanna save in a file on my server

Comment: in fact i wanna create a folder in my server and save xml files created in angular to 
 my server

Answer (score 0):

You must use file system (fs) in your node server. I created this express.js example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let body = '';
  let dir = './example-dir';
  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  req.on('end', function() {
    fs.writeFile(dir + '/result.xml', body, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      res.send('You just created new xml file!')
    });
  });
})
```

At first you get xml file from your request, next  you check if desired directory exists and then you save your file.

In your Angular app remember to send your request as `application/xml`

Comment: Do you need that fs imported in angular

Comment: No, this example is for backend, your node.js server. You can't use files system in your angular app.

Comment: Did you do this project? Please put  a link here I couldn't do it